# SSL Issue while accessing AWS using kubectl

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl

I am trying to access Amazon EKS environment using kubectl but getting an error:

```
could not get token: could not create session: LoadCustomCABundleError: failed to load custom CA bundle PEM file
```

Investigating further I found I am not able to access my AWS environment because of SSL certificate issue.
I tried `curl https://AE7A918B4BD2D7875DAF1E4C32FD7D2D.yl4.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com` and got an error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Anyone faced a similar issue or can help me resolve this issue?